# union several arrays of same flag(date for example) efficiently

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, programming

Suppose I have several arrays from data files which look like:

```
arrayi = {{datei1, xi11, xi21, ...}, {datei2, xi12, xi22, ...}, ..., {datein, xi1n, xi2n ,...}}
```

The `arrayi`s are from different data sources so `Length@arrayi` and `Length@arrayj` is generally different. For certain `arrayi`, the flags (`datei1`, for example) might not be continuous (on some days the observation were missed).

I want to combine all the `arrayi`s data for comparison, so data with the same flag (dates in this example) should be selected and put together.

Consider a simple example, in which there are only two test data arrays:

```
len1 = 1000;
 array1 = 
   RandomSample[
     Transpose@{
       DateRange[{2001, 1, 1}, DatePlus[{2001, 1, 1}, len1 - 1]], 
       Range@len1 + RandomReal[{0, 1}, len1]
     },
     Round@(0.95*len1)
   ]
```

and

```
len2 = 1500;
array2 = 
  RandomSample[
    Transpose@{
      DateRange[{2001, 1, 7}, DatePlus[{2001, 1, 7}, len2 - 1]],
      Range@len2, 
      (Range@len2)^2 + RandomReal[{0, 1}, len2]
    },
    Round@(0.95*len2)
  ]
```

where `Dimensions@array1` is `{95, 2}` and `Dimensions@array2` is `{142, 3}`.

I can combine data of same date in `array1` and `array2` by

```
combinearray1array2 = 
  DeleteCases[
    (i = 0; {i++; date = #[[1]]; #, Select[array2, #[[1]] == date &]} & /@ array1),
    x_ /; x[[2]] == {}
  ];
```

In fact I don't care the exact form of `combinearray1array2`, I only want that every line of `combinearray1array2` contains information from both `array1` and `array2` of same flag (which is date here).

However, this code is very slow and will be slower for 3 or more arrays. Are there any other ways for the same job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way which I find is fractionally faster than @march's and I think scales better when combining information from more than 2 arrays (as you say you are interested in) is simply:

```
    GroupBy[Join[array1, array2, array3], First -> Rest, Join];
```

This produces a well formatted output straight away (imo), for the shorter length 10 and 15 arrays:

[image]

For timings I find with the len 1000 and 1500 arrays:

- @Harry's method - 1.24 s
- @march's method - 0.0083 s
- This method     - 0.0057 s

When also incorporating a 3rd array of length 2000:

- @march's method - 0.01 s
- This method     - 0.0089 s

EDIT:

As @eldo pointed out, this gives the combination of the two data sets, not just those entries for comparison. For that we can simply take:

```
    assoc = GroupBy[Join[array1, array2, array3], First -> Rest, Join];
    Select[assoc, Length[#] == 2 &]
```

which gives:
[image]

Timing wise it's now essentially the same as @march, maybe slightly more compact when considering more than 2 arrays.

Comment: This doesn't give at all what the OP asked for

Comment: How so? Have I misunderstood something? Fundamentally if does what is asked - combine the data from separate arrays under the same flag. For example, for {2001,1,7} we have both the record from array 1 {7.69853} and those from array 2 {1, 1.0447}. Yes they are separate, but maybe Harry still wants that, if not, flattening it is trivial. Yes the solution is still as associations, but again converting to a list is trivial. Have I missed something?

Comment: Ah, I think I do see how my answer is not quite what was requested, standby, I'll see if I can sort it.

Comment: You should only keep items like `key -> {_List, _List}`, i.e. overlapping dates

Comment: Indeed, I've updated my answer correspondingly. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Very nice now +1

Answer (score 4):

We will use `Association`s. There are many ways to form these `Association`s from your data. I will choose one and re-format it at the end. Using your provided data, we form `Association`s that use the date as the `Key`:

```
assoc1 = Association[Rule @@@ array1];
assoc2 = Association[#1 -> {##2} & @@@ array2];
```

We then "intersect" these intersections, taking only the `Key`s that are the same:

```
assoc = KeyIntersection[{assoc1, assoc2}];
```

When I ran `AbsoluteTiming` on your code and the `Association` code, it took 1.84 seconds and 0.012 seconds, respectively, which is a pretty nice speed-up.

To get back the data in the form that you have it, we can do

```
Apply[{#1, Sequence @@ #2} &, Transpose@Normal@assoc, {2}]
```

---

For the purposes of illustration, let's consider the following, much smaller example:

```
len1 = 10;
array1 =
  RandomSample[
    Transpose@{
      DateRange[{2001, 1, 1}, DatePlus[{2001, 1, 1}, len1 - 1]],
      Range@len1 + RandomReal[{0, 1}, len1]
    },
    Round@(0.95*len1)
  ]
len2 = 15;
array2 = 
  RandomSample[
    Transpose@{
      DateRange[{2001, 1, 7}, DatePlus[{2001, 1, 7}, len2 - 1]],
      Range@len2,
      (Range@len2)^2 + RandomReal[{0, 1}, len2]
    }, 
    Round@(0.95*len2)
  ]
```

[image]

Your code yields

```
combinearray1array2 = 
  DeleteCases[
    (i = 0; {i++; date = #[[1]]; #, Select[array2, #[[1]] == date &]} & /@ array1),
    x_ /; x[[2]] == {}
  ]
```

[image]

My code is

```
assoc1 = Association[Rule @@@ array1]
assoc2 = Association[#1 -> {##2} & @@@ array2]
assoc = KeyIntersection[{assoc1, assoc2}]
```

[image]

To get back the data in the form that you have it, we can do

```
Apply[{#1, Sequence @@ #2} &, Transpose@Normal@assoc, {2}]
```

yielding

[image]